# Datetime picker transparent background out of the box?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

This is out of the box mvc3 stock grade plain vanilla jquery behavior?  Is this default styling behavior?  How do I make it NOT transparent? Thx!

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
</script>

@Html.TextBox("xxx", "", new { @class = "date" })
```

[image]

Comment: Did you include the jQuery UI Style Sheet?

Comment: Yep, thanks - either works:       <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 47, accepted):

My guess is you are indeed missing either the stylesheet or the images.

try adding CSS link to

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Thanks: either of the following work just fine:

       <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 8):

I was using a custom theme, so the above suggestion wasnt ideal...

The fix was to add background color to this section

```
/* DatePicker Container */
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 216px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    font: 9pt Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will just work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the files were there, but the BundleConfig.cs file had the file name wrong. The file name was "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" but BundleConfig.cs had the file listed as "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css".

Answer (score 0):

Just Give the `z-index` style value for the input field a higher value and also make the position `relative`, i.e.,

```
position: relative; z-index: 10000;
```

It will work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in style tab

```
.ui-datepicker {  background: white; }
```