# How to make <input type="date"> supported on all browsers? Any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm working with HTML5 elements input attributes and only Google Chrome supports the date, time attributes. I tried [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) but I can't understand on how to integrate it on my website(on how to code it/what is the syntax/includes). Any code snippet there on how to work with date, time attributes to all browsers.

Comment: What kind of control are you using a Datepicker?? maybe JQuery UI would be perfect??

Comment: Please note that if you're not already relying on jQueryUI for something, including its gargantuan weight just to shim a date input should not be a default decision.

Comment: A complete example is provided at http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Any browser that does not support the input type `date` will default to the standard type, which is `text`, so all you have to do is check the type **property** *(not the attribute)*, if it's not `date`, the date input is not supported by the browser, and you add your own datepicker:

```
if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
    $('[type="date"]').datepicker();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2AaFk/1/)

You can of course use any datepicker you want, jQuery UI's datepicker is probably the one most commonly used, but it does add quite a bit of javascript if you're not using the UI library for anything else, but there are hundreds of alternative datepickers to choose from.

The `type` attribute never changes, the browser will only fall back to the default `text` type for the property, so one has to check the property.
The attribute can still be used as a selector, as in the example above.

Comment: Might be better to use jQuery to check the property rather than dropping down to the DOM? `$('input').prop('type') != 'date'`

Comment: You may also some filter for the text input you want to hold bits of text, could be done by adding a class="date" or something

Comment: While "type" of the input changes to "text" if "date" is not supported, the attribute "type" remains "date". So this can easily used as selector. I have updated the fiddle this way: http://jsfiddle.net/2AaFk/34/

Comment: @MichaelWyraz as I checked your fiddle , it seems notworking on safari browser.

Comment: This worked for me, just notice that I dind't have the required css and I found it on this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29791769/1339326

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Anyone has the same issue, just add this filter to your `functions.php` file :  `add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );`

Comment: this worked great for me, but i had to include the proper jquery (jquery-ui.js) "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>"

Answer (score 14):

Modernizr doesn't actually change anything about how the new HTML5 input types are handled. It's a feature *detector*, not a shim (except for `<header>`, `<article>`, etc., which it shims to be handled as block elements similar to `<div>`).

To use `<input type='date'>`, you'd need to check `Modernizr.inputtypes.date` in your own script, and if it's false, turn on another plugin that provides a date selector. You have thousands to choose from; Modernizr maintains [a non-exhaustive list of polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) that might give you somewhere to start. Alternatively, you could just let it go - all browsers fall back to `text` when presented with an input type they don't recognize, so the worst that can happen is that your user has to type in the date. (You might want to give them a placeholder or use something like jQuery.maskedinput to keep them on track.)

Answer (score 11):

You asked for Modernizr example, so here you go. This code uses Modernizr to detect whether the 'date' input type is supported. If it isn't supported, then it fails back to JQueryUI datepicker.

Note: You will need to download JQueryUI and possibly change the paths to the CSS and JS files in your own code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Modernizer Detect 'date' input type</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-1.7-development-only.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
                    console.log("The 'date' input type is not supported, so using JQueryUI datepicker instead.");
                    $("#theDate").datepicker();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="theDate" type="date"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Note that for Modernizr 3, you have to generate the config using https://modernizr.com/download?inputtypes-setclasses and compile the javascript as described at https://modernizr.com/docs/#downloading-modernizr

Answer (score 7):

```
   <script>
      var datefield = document.createElement("input")
      datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
      if (datefield.type != "date") { // if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
         document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
         document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
         document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n')
      }
   </script>

 <script>
    if (datefield.type != "date") { // if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
       jQuery(function($) { // on document.ready
           $('#birthday').datepicker();
       }); <- missing semicolon
    }
 </script>
```

```
<body>
 <form>
   <b>Date of birth:</b>
   <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" size="20">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" name="B1">
 </form>
</body>
```

**[SOURCE 1](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck2.shtml)**  & **[SOURCE 2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-cross-browser-datepickers-in-minutes--net-20236)**

Answer (score 6):

This is bit of an opinion piece, but we had great success with [WebShims](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/). It can decay cleanly to use jQuery datepicker if native is not available. [Demo here](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-date.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `<script src="modernizr.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section, and the script will add classes which help you to separate the two cases: if it's supported by the current browser, or if it's not.

Plus follow the links posted in this thread. It will help you: [HTML5 input type date, color, range support in Firefox and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455506/html5-input-type-date-color-range-support-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Version 50.0.2661.87 m does not support the mm-dd-yy format when assigned to a variable. It uses yy-mm-dd. IE and Firefox work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

best easy and working solution i have found is, working on following browsers

1. Google Chrome
2. Firefox
3. Microsoft Edge
4. Safari

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <h2>Poly Filler Script for Date/Time</h2>
   <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="date" />
       <br/><br/>
       <input type="time" />
   </form>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
   <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
   <script>
     webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
     webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {type: 'date'});
     webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {type: 'time'});
     webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

## Two-Script-Include-Solution (2019):

Just include **[Better-Dom](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dom)** and **[Better-Dateinput-Polyfill](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dateinput-polyfill)** in your scripts section.

Here is a Demo:
http://chemerisuk.github.io/better-dateinput-polyfill/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Date picker works for all browsers(IE, Firefox, Chrome)</title>
<script>
    var datefield = document.createElement("input")
    datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
    if (datefield.type != "date") { // if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
        document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n')
    }
</script>

<script>
    if (datefield.type != "date") { // if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        jQuery(function($) { // on document.ready
            $('#start_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
            $('#end_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
        })
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="start_date" id="start_date" type="date" required>
    <input name="end_date" id="end_date" required>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with this, maintaining the UK dd/mm/yyyy format, I initially used the answer from adeneo https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021130/243905 but that didnt work in safari for me so changed to this, which as far as I can tell works all over - using the jquery-ui datepicker, jquery validation.

```
if ($('[type="date"]').prop('type') !== 'date') {
    //for reloading/displaying the ISO format back into input again
    var val = $('[type="date"]').each(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val !== undefined && val.indexOf('-') > 0) {
            var arr = val.split('-');
            $(this).val(arr[2] + '/' + arr[1] + '/' + arr[0]);
        }
    });

    //add in the datepicker
    $('[type="date"]').datepicker(datapickeroptions);

    //stops the invalid date when validated in safari
    jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) {
        var shortDateFormat = "dd/mm/yy";
        var res = true;
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate(shortDateFormat, value);
        } catch (error) {
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```