# Loading jQuery UI datepicker when native HTML5 date input type not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

While `<input type="date">` is not common for desktop, this is the preferred method for mobile.

I'm trying to implement the fallback code at the bottom of this section:
http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date

```
<form>
  <input type="date">
</form>

<script>
  var i = document.createElement("input");
  i.setAttribute("type", "date");
  if (i.type == "text") {

    // No native date picker support :(
    // Use Dojo/jQueryUI/YUI/Closure to create one,
    // then dynamically replace that <input> element.
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.scr = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.href = "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

    $(function() {
       $.datepicker.setDefaults(
          $.extend($.datepicker.regional['']);
       );
    });
  }
</script>
```

Using the above logic, anything within `$(function())` throws a console error and datepicker is undefinied. How do I rewrite this so that jQueryUI script and style only shows up when native datepicker isn't available?

I'm trying to keep http requests down and overall page performance faster on these pages for mobile browsers and Chrome since they all have native datepickers available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the script loads before you can use it. I suggest using $.getScript to load it.

```
$.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js", function(){
   $.datepicker.setDefaults(
      $.extend($.datepicker.regional[''];)
   );
});
```

Also you have to use a `<link>` tag to insert a stylesheet into your document not a style tag.

Comment: Interesting, that worked. How would I load the stylesheet for jQueryUI? The same way I've already been doing?

Comment: @micah just as you have it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why but the method I have to dynamically insert the jQueryUI style tag isn't working. Is there a better method?

Comment: @micah use a `link` tag not a `style` tag.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I also had to add another line for `rel="stylesheet"` so that it knew what kind of link it was. Now it's working as intended. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another fallback method for `[input type="date"]` support that I found helpful.

What happens:  The browser is tested to see if it supports the input type of date.  If it does, business as usual.  If it does not, then you can load the scripts and styles that are necessary to create a nice Date Picker control.

I used

- [YepNope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) to handle the conditional loading.
- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to conduct the test.
- jQuery & jQuery UI for the [Date Picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) control.

After including the scripts above in whatever way that you choose, you then add this script to your page to handle the conditional fallback.

```
yepnope({
    test: Modernizr.inputtypes && Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
    nope: [
          //'scripts/jquery.js','scripts/jquery-ui.js','css/jquery-ui.css'
          '~/scripts/app/dateinput.html5shim.js'
        ]
    });
```

-- jQuery, jQueryUI, Modernizr, and YepNope are all loaded in a bundle for my project.

My datepicker script is copied directly from the tutorial below.  This just initializes the jQuery UI control for all input elements of type date when the DOM is ready

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='date']").datepicker();
});
```

This answer comes from the always helpful Chris Coyier of css-tricks fame.  Full tutorial here: http://css-tricks.com/progressively-enhancing-html5-forms/

Comment: To only apply this where the browser doesn't have built in functionality:
`if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
    $('[type="date"]').datepicker();
}` 
From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives