# Jquery Modernizr datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, modernizr

I downloaded modernizr.js from it's website.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Modernizr</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/modernizr.custom.62854.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>



<script>
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
    nope: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery-ui.css'],
    complete: function () {
        $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I added a datepicker but if i run website , i can not see anything where i miss ?

Comment: First thing you need to do is move the `script` block inside `body` tag

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Second point, I don't see any `input[type=date]` in your HTML

Comment: Add `<input/>` element!

Comment: may you please answer with html code i will accept best answer if you can help thanks

Comment: Please see [How to make <input type=“date”> supported on all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18020950/873282) for other answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your html.

```
<input type="date"/>
```

You have datepicker based on an `<input>` element.

```
$('input[type=date]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/)**

**[Fiddle Without Modernizr](http://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/1/)**

---

- Include the `<script>` tag with Modernizr code, in the `<head>` tag.
- And for implementing **[DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)** you should include **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)** reference.

---

**Note :**

**[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/)** cannot detect that date inputs create a datepicker, its design, the color input create a colorpicker, and so on; it will detect that the input values are sanitized based on the spec.

---

Comment: i see date right now however modernizr does not change design of datepicker why ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'design'? Any specific feature?

Comment: i am new for modernizr.If ı use moderniz , datepicker must be different(good designed). What is difference between using modernizr and not using modernizr for datepicker ?

Comment: See, You are using modernizr to just text if input-date is supported. You can use `<input type="text">` **[Check this Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/1/)**

Answer (score 5):

@user3705822 modernizr is not intended to modify the design, it just tell you what features are supported by different browsers so that you can act accordingly.

> Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features
>   in the user’s browser.

what you are looking for is something like this http://uniformjs.com/ or http://jqueryui.com/