# Using Native Datepicker in Angular webApplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Is there a way for a AngularJs based application to use native datepicker when running on a device ? For example in a android device i want to show the native datepicker so that user can swipe up and down.

*Because in desktop there is no native datepicker, i'm thinking about to check the target that web application is running and show bootsrap-ui datepicker.*

Comment: See [How to make <input type=“date”> supported on all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18020950/1700321).

Comment: I can use that to choose which datepicker to show depending in which browser the application runs. Thanks.
But how can i use android native datepicker to show in the application ?

Comment: In my search so far, i have not find any library that can open the native android datepicker through AngularJS. I suppose that some jquery js could maybe do the job but there is **NOT** something similar with this. It may have also performance problems with AngularJS to compile pure android java code, so a date picker more similar with original datepicker nut in JS library would be a more reasonable solution.

I remind that i was looking an access to the folloing dialog in native way through JQuery.


 http://i.stack.imgur.com/Anby9.png