# How to create date inputs in a form without using the type date

Tags: php, html, forms

Firefox doesnt support the input type date. What are the alternatives for taking a date into an input form. I have tried creating inputs for the seperate day, month and year but i dont know how to take them and store them in one variable in the MySQL database

Comment: Check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

To create datepicker you can use following code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Add following statement into your js file

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Note - `'#datepicker'` - It's the **id** of control which we want to use as **date-picker**.

Answer (score 0):

One easy alternative is jquery [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript as suggested in the above replies.

If you really do not want or cannot use JavaScript (but you should as it's really straight-forward), just pass the three separate values (day, month and year), to your PHP script via GET or POST.

Retrieve them via the `$_REQUEST` array (for example: `$_REQUEST['day']` if you input field is called *day*), and do the appropriate checks (for example you don't want your 'month' value to be negative or above 12) and, if you want the date to be a single variable, just concatenate your three values and insert them into your db, with a simple query, as you prefer.

TLDR: Use, for example, JQuery as stated in other replies but you can achieve this also without JavaScript.