# Display date format in a date control in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I am trying to use a date input field on a page and trying to make it work across chrome and Internet explorer. To make it work it work on IE I have used following code :

```
if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
    $('[type="date"]').datepicker();
}
```

This works fine. The issue that the date format is displayed in chrome [image] but not in IE. [image]

Can anyone help me with how I can display the format in IE as well.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what your code does:  if the first element with attribute type = date has attribute type that isn't date then make all elements with attribute type date a datepicker.  huh?   i.e. you code does *nothing* and you're just displaying the default browser date picker, not the `.datepicker()`.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=input-date

Comment: @freedomn-m I think OP meant to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193294/how-can-i-tell-if-a-browser-supports-input-type-date

Comment: @mplungjan Can't really tell if they're *trying* to use `.datepicker()` (as tagged with [jquery-ui]) and thinking that the chrome default `input type=date` *is* the jquery-ui datepicker and wondering why IE is not giving them a jquery-ui datepicker as well.

Comment: @freedomn-m it might actually work come to think of it. They have type="date" which IE might convert to type="text" which will then return the property of "text" instead of "date"

Comment: I just want to display the format inside the input field like mm/dd/yyyy. My date field and datepicker is working in all browsers.

Comment: @boms I recommend you just use `<input type='text' class='usedatepicker'>` and `$(".usedatepicker").datepicker()` to convert them all to datepickers which will show the value as a date, then all will be fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m my logic of converting to datepicker is working fine. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives All I want is to display the date format like chrome shows. Refer images in question above

Comment: @mplungjan my question is not about how to add support for date field. I know such questions have been answered. I just want to know how to display date format inside the input field in IE like mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: I think there is something going on. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fLrojy7t/
we get `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'` regardless

Comment: Your fiddle wasn't using https - I see you've updated it.  `$("input").datepicker();` converts both to datepicker (not tested in crap browser)

Comment: See my answer. I now understand the question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the "Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'" issue in IE11

It has something to do with the loading of jQuery UI - the CSS MUST be loaded too

Using the latest jQuery and UI

NOTE: You will NOT have the dd-mm-yyyy spinner controls in jQuery-UI datepicker that is used in the native HTML5 datepicker in Chrome and Edge

```js
$(function() {
  let $date = $("input[type=date]");
  if ($date.prop("type") != "date") {
    $date.attr("type", "text")
    console.log("Crap browser")
  }
  $("[type=text].date").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
UI datepicker in IE only<br/> 
<input class="date" type="date" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" />
<hr/>
UI datepicker in both IE and Chrome<br/>
<input class="date" type="text"  placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" />
```

Comment: I still can't see the format mm/dd/yyyy inside the date field in IE.

Comment: Ahhh - that is because datepicker does not have that functionality. I have added a placeholder

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Adding a placeholder helps. Thanks.

Comment: Whew. It was not obvious because I for a long while got an actual error in the IE implementation

Comment: IE can be tough sometimes for developers :)